# I'm facing problem on running Mocha test. how to resolve this issue?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

[image: I'm getting the error shown in image what is the proble. I'm begginer to Selenium Webdriver with Mocha]

Is there any problem of package.json file or i'm not giving proper command to run the file.

Comment: The error message tells you the problem; the file is not digitally signed.

Comment: how can i sign file digitally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set execution policy to unrestricted in powershell.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Thanks. Was need to set executionpolicy from Allsigned to unrestricted